# How to get android:installLocation value of a specified app?

Tags: android, apk, android-sdcard

It's possible to get if an app is currently installed on the sd-card or not, by using the next code, using the [ApplicationInfo flags](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html#flags) :

```
final boolean isInstalledOnExternalStorage=(applicationInfo.flags&ApplicationInfo.FLAG_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!=0;
```

However, what I'd like to know is how to get the requested installation location as specified by the manifest (described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#install)) of an installed app.

Sadly, as much as I've read here and on the documentation, I can't find out where this attribute's values can be fetched, unless maybe I'd need to parse the APK file myself...

So, how do I achieve it? Is it even possible using the normal Android framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this code, it works in my app:

```
PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(mPackageName, 0);
if (packageInfo.installLocation != PackageInfo.INSTALL_LOCATION_INTERNAL_ONLY) {
    .....
}
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#installLocation
was introduced in API 21

But this field exists even in Android 2.3
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3_r1/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.java/

Comment: yes, it is taking info from manifest. (android:installLocation attribute value)

Comment: ok, thank you. I don't even remember why I asked this question, but it seems like you've found the answer, so I will now tick it.